# Tweet button not working in IE9

Tags: twitter

Tweet button renders in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari but not IE9.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="url" data-text="text">Tweet</a>

<script>!function(d,s,id) {
    var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
        js=d.createElement(s);
        js.id=id;
        js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
    }
}
(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
</script>
```

Comment: Does the script console report any errors?

Comment: http://www.iesucks.info/tag/ieshit/

Comment: Cthulhu, I don't see any errors. On the site, the word Tweet appears as blue link, the tweet that results from this link does not include correct data attributes. You can see at http://policyvote.com